# Simple bash scripts issues

Tags: bash, shell

Im using mineos (minecraft os) and it has a few available commands to pick up a few bits of info.

1. Pull the pid of a set server
2. Count instances of a string in the game log
3. Trigger event when count hits X

This works fine for pulling the required info:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /usr/games/minecraft
count=`grep -c "\[SEVERE\]" /home/mc/servers/testingmode/server.log`
pid=`./mineos_console.py -s testingmode get pid`


./mineos_console.py -s testingmode console say "$count"
./mineos_console.py -s testingmode console say "$pid"
```

But as soon as I add an if it throws out "pid:command not found":

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /usr/games/minecraft
count=`grep -c "\[SEVERE\]" /home/mc/servers/testingmode/server.log`
pid =`./mineos_console.py -s testingmode get pid`

if [ "$count" -gt 400 ];then
./mineos_console.py -s testingmode console say "$count"
./mineos_console.py -s testingmode console say "$pid"
fi
```

Anyone know why or a nice solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the line

```
pid =`./mineos_console.py -s testingmode get pid`
```

you have a space between `pid` and the `=`.  Removing that should fix the problem.